# Repeating event in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I want to create repeating event like "sunday and monday at 3:00pm in september and october". How could I do this?

Or I must create multiply events with different date?

Comment: "In September and October" isn't *repeating*.

Comment: But sunday and monday are repeating in september (and october)

Comment: Either you mean that you want a repeating schedule to have a limited duration, starting on Sep 1 and finishing on Oct31 , or you want it to repeat every year for these two months. That isn't a repeating schedule.

Comment: In any case, this isn't a programming question. It's about the end-user functionality of a product. You should probably ask at `sharepoint.stackexchange.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just create 1 event with Recurrence.

- Choose weekly option
- Recur every 1 week
- Select Sunday and Monday
- Start Date : 1 September
- End By : 31 October

but if the time period is not in row (eg: September & November), 
you need to create 2 recurrence event on each month.

Comment: Thanks! Its what I need!